# Conditional Agregation for numbered states

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, pivot

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around a SQL Query. I'm thinking that somehow conditional agregation can be used, but here is my situation:

I have the following table:

```
+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+------------------+
| Email_Name | Email_Id | Subject_Line | Customer_Id | Interaction_Type |
+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+------------------+
| Email1     |        1 | Hello_1      |           1 | SENT             |
| Email2     |        1 | Hello_1      |           2 | SENT             |
| Email3     |        1 | Hello_1      |           3 | OPEN             |
| Email4     |        1 | Hello_1      |           4 | OPEN             |
| Email5     |        1 | Hello_1      |           5 | CLICK            |
| Email6     |        1 | Hello_1      |           6 | SENT             |
+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Usually, the input data is ordered by customer ID, for example a email sent to 100 people will show up a 100 times (per customer id). If 50 emails are opened, I will have an additional 50 lines of the email with OPEN state and so on.

What I want to do is aggregate the data so I have a single line for each Email ID followed by 3 columns OPEN/SENT/CLICK with numbers saying how many times it was sent/opened/clicked.

Can it be done? Using MySql. Thank you kindly.

Comment: It's mysql 8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation:

```
select email_id, 
       sum(Interaction_Type = 'SENT') as num_sent,
       sum(Interaction_Type = 'OPEN') as num_open,
       sum(Interaction_Type = 'CLICK') as num_click
from t
group by email_id;
```

Comment: That was it! Awesome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You do want conditional aggregation.

This works by grouping the dataset by `email_name`, and then performing conditional `sum`s for each of the `interaction_type`s, like so:

```
select 
    email_name,
    sum(interaction_type = 'SENT') sent,
    sum(interaction_type = 'OPEN') open,
    sum(interaction_type = 'CLICK') click
from mytable
group by email_name
```

In MySQL, conditional expressions, when evaluated in numeric context, yield `1` when fulfilled and `0` when not. So an expression like `sum(interaction_type = 'SENT')` increases by `1` for each record where `interaction_type = 'SENT'`.

Comment: Similar answer to what was above, but thank you very much for the explination. You rock!